# APRegisterExt not saving data on APInvoiceEntry

Tags: acumatica

Build 18.203.0006
Page: AP301000

Good day, I have extended the APRegister Class by adding 2 new checkbox fields. I want to iterate through al the APTran transactions and look for suIDs that start with FBL and GAS. If I find them the new tick boxes should tick.

Currently, the fields(tick boxes) do not save to the database. I am not sure how to tell Acumatica the APRegisterExt has updated.

APInvoiceEntry_Extension:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APRegisterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APRegister>
  {
    #region UsrGroupAEmail
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="GroupA Email")]

    public virtual bool? UsrGroupAEmail { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrGroupAEmail : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrGroupBEmail
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="GroupB Email")]

    public virtual bool? UsrGroupBEmail { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrGroupBEmail : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

APInvoiceEntry_Extension:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
    public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        protected void APInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            APInvoice invoice = e.Row as APInvoice;
            if (invoice == null) return;

            var apRX = invoice.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>();

            PXResultset<APTran> Tlist = PXSelectJoin<APTran,
                                           LeftJoin<POReceiptLine,
                                                 On<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<APTran.receiptNbr>,
                                                And<POReceiptLine.lineNbr, Equal<APTran.receiptLineNbr>>>>,
                                                Where<
                                                      APTran.tranType, Equal<Current<APInvoice.docType>>,
                                                  And<APTran.refNbr, Equal<Current<APInvoice.refNbr>>>>,
                                                  OrderBy<
                                                      Asc<APTran.tranType,
                                                      Asc<APTran.refNbr,
                                                      Asc<APTran.lineNbr>>>>>.Select(Base);

            apRX.UsrGroupBEmail = false;
            apRX.UsrGroupAEmail = false;

            foreach (APTran item in Tlist)
            {
                if (item.SubID.Value.ToString().StartsWith("FBL") || item.SubID.Value.ToString().StartsWith("GAS"))
                {
                    apRX.UsrGroupBEmail = true;
                    cache.SetValue<APRegisterExt.usrGroupBEmail>(e.Row, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    apRX.UsrGroupAEmail = true;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

Can someone please show me the correct way of saving the data to the new tick boxes so that cache updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider moving the logic to APRegister_RowPersisting. 
Importantly, APTran.subID is an Int dataType. 
Read instead the Sub table/DAC during a For Loop of 
Base.Transactions.Select() to detect SubCD startsWith FBL or GAS.

```
foreach(APTran item in Base.Transaction.Select())
{ 
    Sub sub = PXSelect<Sub, 
           Where<Sub.subID, Equal<Required<Sub.subID>>>>
            .Select(graph, item.SubID);

    if (item.SubCD.StartsWith("FBL") || 
                 item.SubCD.StartsWith("GAS"))
    {
         apRX.UsrGroupBEmail = true;
    }
    else
    {
         apRX.UsrGroupAEmail = true;
    }

}
```

To be complete, you may also need to reset both flags during APTran_SubID_FieldUpdated regardless of the changed value:

```
protected void APTran_SubID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, 
        PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated del)
{
    del?.Invoke(sender,e);

    var apRX = Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>();

    apRX.UsrGroupBEmail = false;
    apRX.UsrGroupAEmail = false;
}
```